# Strange behavior of Graphics2D.getDeviceConfiguration()

Tags: java

This is a sketch of my program to illustrate the problem:

```
view = getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(100, 100);

// creating a BufferedImage with size 100x100

Rectangle r = view.createGraphics().getDeviceConfiguration().getBounds();

// this correctly returns a rectangle of 100x100, as in my understanding the device
// is the BufferedImage and its size is 100x100

/* Later a new object is created, where 'view' again is assigned, so it is a different instance variable (even if it were the same object, I would not understand the behavior). */

view = getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(200, 200);

// creating a BufferedImage with size 200x200

Rectangle r = view.createGraphics().getDeviceConfiguration().getBounds();

// now this again returns a rectangle of 100x100, though I would expect it to return
// 200x200 (!?), for some reason the system seems to remember the old settings?
```

I checked the `GraphicsConfiguration` returned by the two calls to `getDeviceConfiguration()` above. It is the same object.

Thanks for any comments!

Comment: What does `view.getWidth()` and `view.getHeight()` return?

Comment: What is `getGraphicsConfiguration()`?

Comment: getWidth() and getHeight() return the correct values,

Comment: I did a simple test and verify the results, not sure I'm that concerned, as I do this (create images this way) all the time and rely on the `getWidth` and `getHeight` values...but that's just me

Comment: geGraphicsConfiguration() returns X11GraphicsConfig[dev=X11GraphicsDevice[screen=0],vis=0x21]

Comment: getWidth() and getHeight() are certainly the more natural way to ask for the size of the image, but I pass around the corresponding Graphics2D objects to draw on them, so I do not know the image object then, and have to ask for the size as described above

Comment: Normally in those cases, I would also pass the width and height, as the size of the available area could have been clipped...